# Handling CDATA escaped XML in Freemarker

Tags: xml, freemarker, cdata

I'm using Freemarker in my project to transform from one XML document to another.
Due to crappy design or choice of canonical message format our supplier has chosen to embed some XML in CDATA escaped fields, probably as their chosen message standard does not handle all types of extensions. For whatever reason I now need to dig into this field and do some xpath queries.

Say ie:

```
<Invoice>
  ..
  <Note><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><a><b>Value</b></a>]]></Note>
</Invoice>
```

Anyone has an idea how to get value "a/b/text()" in this kind of scenario?

I've thought about trying to clean the CDATA section manually and then parse it as XML, but my hopes are that Freemarker could do this for me.

Comment: Very trollish... I thought my question was quite clear. And for all XML fanatics out there: YES I know that you're not supposed to parse CDATA sections. Been to that lesson, agree completely.. But in this case I have no choice as the supplier is big and won't unfortunately listen to what small me has to say about XML standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FreeMarker doesn't parse XML, it just calls the usual API-s to do that, so FreeMarker can't help here. You will have to load the XML file into a `String` (`char[]` or whatever), remove those CDATA "tags", then parse the resulting `String` to DOM tree with  `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder`, and pass that to FreeMarker. You will probably want to call `NodeMode.simplify(theDomTree)` before that however.

Comment: You're right. I missed saying that I've parsed the wrapping XML into a DOM and use XPath queries inside FM to fetch the individual fields. My Solution was to bind a utility class to a bean and send the CDATA fields to it together with an XPath expression that the bean evaluates. Not the smoothest solution but it certainly worked.

Answer (score 1):

I think your suggestion of reparsing the XML might be your best bet. [CDATA](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) means that it should be treated as such: character data.

Answer (score 0):

This post is a bit aged, but why not use the content:encoded marker with your cdata?

```
<content:encoded><![CDATA[ ${ body } ]]> </content:encoded>
```